# Adding Subviews to NSView show up, but can not be removed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, addsubview, nsviewcontroller

In my application window I have two NSViews. On the left the NSView ("Menu") contains a few buttons. When one of the buttons is clicked it should change the contents of the right NSView ("Content").

For each of the views on the right I have a separate NSViewControllers that get loaded and their views gets added as a subview. When a further button gets pressed on the left the added subviews on the right should be removed and the new view should be loaded as a subview.

To accomplish this I load my Menu in AppDelegate with the following:

```
 MenuVC *menuSubView = [[MenuVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuVC" bundle: nil];
    menuSubView.contentView = (NSView*)[self contentView];
    [[self menuView] addSubview:[menuSubView view]];
```

This works fine. As you can see I have a NSView pointer in the Menu VC which points to the contentView so that I can populate it with the subviews.

Now as a method for one of the button presses I do the following:

```
SomeContentVC *subView = [[SomeContentVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeContentVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.contentView addSubview:[subView view]];
```

This does not work.

If I however add a subview from the awakeFromNib method of the MenuViewController implementation (in the case of default content when the app opens) it works. However when I try to remove that subview using

```
[[self.contentView setSubviews:[NSArray array]];
```

I can't. Interesting is also that if I try to count the number of subviews (even after having added one in the awakeFromNib method) it returns 0 subviews for self.contentView.  Why? How can I get it to work properly?

Thanks

Comment: What's self.contentView? As far as I know NSViewController doesn't have such a property, unless you're creating it yourself.

Comment: In the AppDelegate it is an NSView pointer pointing to the right NSView (the content part of my application). In the MenuVC I also have a NSView pointer which gets populated from the AppDelegate when it created and I pass along AppDelegate's pointer so that I can populate the correct NSView in the main application window. Maybe this helps https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rsaZ6LZLeqM/T4PCBu-z43I/AAAAAAAAAAo/wS9__tdNxmo/s798/Screen%2520Shot%25202012-04-10%2520at%252007.13.39.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that messaging self.contentView achieves nothing except, for some things, returning 0 probably means that self.contentView is nil.

Do you perhaps have two instances of MenuVC by accident? Perhaps one instantiated in a NIB and one instantiated in code?

When in doubt, log everything.  Log `self` in various methods.  Log `menuSubView` just after you create it.  Log `menuSubView.contentView` just after you assign it. Etc. Eventually, you'll probably see that you're interacting with different objects than you thought you were.

Comment: That was it... I still had an NSObject in the NIB of the MenuViewController... THANKS!